# Spring Boot MVC: css/js files read as JSON

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, nginx-ingress

I am using Spring Boot MVC application and have got two instances of it running with nginx(k8s ingress) at the front; There are good number of times, I see in the Web Inspector (F12) that js or css files are getting tried as json resulting in 500 and immediate 2nd attempt succeeds.

[image]

The code that adds this css seems okay:

```
<link href="/css/application.css" th:href="@{/css/application.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

btw, I am using Thymeleaf.

Also, it works fine if the number of instances are just one.

Logs from nginx:

> xxx.xxx.0.4 - [xxx.xxx.0.4] - - [20/Sep/2019:10:27:28 +0000] "GET
>   /css/application.css HTTP/2.0" 500 6987 "https://mydev.com/index"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/69.0" 28 0.370 [mydev-8080] xxx.xxx.0.30:8080 7000 0.368 500
>   xxxxxxxaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> xxx.xxx.0.4 - [xxx.xxx.0.4] - - [20/Sep/2019:10:27:28 +0000] "GET
>   /css/application.css HTTP/2.0" 200 4360 "https://mydev.com/index"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/69.0" 64 0.004 [mydev-8080] xxx.xxx.0.44:8080 19144 0.004 200
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

How would this be happening when the  tag specifically looking to load the type as css but browsers (including chrome and firefox) are trying to load as json?

Comment: Can you show us more details about the requests? More precisely, can you see whether there's any difference between these two calls (request headers being sent, path, HTTP method, ...).

Comment: @g00glen00b added logs from nginx but there is hardly any difference in these two lines which are printed one after another.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like there's a significant difference. Can you also open the details of each request within the network interface (F12). Such as which headers are being sent, the HTTP method, ... .